# AcquireToken_In_Progress: Error during login call - login is already in progress

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm calling microsoft graph api too get user's from azure portal, at that time I'm unable to get users instead of that I need User list, and also I'm getting dialog of login in microsoft.

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "app-id",
    redirectUri: `http://localhost:port`,
    authority: "auth_url",
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
};

const graphScopes = [
  "User.ReadBasic.All",
  "User.Read.All",
  "User.ReadWrite.All",
  "Directory.Read.All",
  "Directory.AccessAsUser.All",
  "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
];

const options = {
  loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
  tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + "/auth.html",
};


const msalApplication = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
const scope = new MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(graphScopes);
const authProvider = new ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(msalApplication, scope);

const option = {
  authProvider,
};

const client = Client.initWithMiddleware(option);
```

And I'm using this code for calling api:

```
const getUser = async () => {
  let list = [];
  try {
      list = await client.api(“https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$top=5”).header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual").get();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  return list;
};
```